# GET http://localhost:6001/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=MloS95c net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, socket.io

I am very new laravel broadcasting. I am working with redis, socket.io and laravel echo. When i reflesh the page this is write on console

> GET http://localhost:6001/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=MloS95c
>   net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

My Test Event:

```
namespace App\Events;

use Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel; use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels; use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PrivateChannel; use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PresenceChannel; use Illuminate\Foundation\Events\Dispatchable; use Illuminate\Broadcasting\InteractsWithSockets; use Illuminate\Contracts\Broadcasting\ShouldBroadcast;

class TestEvent {
    use SerializesModels;
    public $message;

    /**
     * Create a new event instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($message)
    {
        $this->message = $message;

    }

    /**
     * Get the channels the event should broadcast on.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel|array
     */
    public function broadcastOn()
    {
        return new Channel ('Message');
    }

}
```

My head :

```
<script src="http://{{ Request::getHost() }}:6001/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>

<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

My Controller:

```
public function dev(){
        event(new TestEvent("Hello"));
        return view('home');
    }
```

My Js file:

```
window.Echo.channel(`Message`)
    .listen('TestEvent', (data) => {
        console.log(data);
    });
```

Comment: In your `config/app.php` file, did you enable  `App\Providers\BroadcastServiceProvider::class`  and is your user logged in? https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/broadcasting go through this.

Comment: yes enabled broadcastserviceprovider, also logged in. Console log didnt working when i run event

Comment: in your event class, add `implements ShouldBroadcast` after `class TestEvent`, so it should look like `class TestEvent implements ShouldBroadcast` and in the event use `use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;`

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error as the laravel echo server is not started. Inside your package.json file add under script the following line.

````
"scripts": {
    "start": "laravel-echo-server start",
     ```
},
````

Now you need to go to the console and run `npm start` command into your project root directory.  It will start the lavavel echo server and the error will be gone.